# Getting a strongly typed Model from MVC3 Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've found a property of my helper that I think will give me access to the properties of my model, but I was hoping to get an instance of the model itself.  I have a view with a strongly typed Model.  One property of the model, is a collection of other models (TestModel).  I would like to render each of the items in the collection in a standard way.  So, my view code would look something like this.

```
@foreach(var testModel in @Model.Items){
    @Html.DisplayViewerFor(@testModel)
}
```

My helper looks something like this.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayViewerFor(this HtmlHelper<TestModel> helper, Expression<Func<TestModel>> expression, bool rightAligned = true) {
        var modelData = helper.ViewData;
        var prop = modelData[""];
        var outterDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
        outterDiv.AddCssClass(rightAligned ? "item-display-right" : "item-display");

        //Create other markup using modelData here
        //Would prefer to use an instance of TestModel


        return new MvcHtmlString(outterDiv.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a value, not an expression.

Extend the non-generic `HtmlHelper` class and take a raw `TestModel` instance as a parameter.

You only need an expression tree if you want to find out the property name.

Comment: That answered more than just this one question I have concerning many of the issues I'm having.  I need to find more info on the expression tree.  I think I can find the solution to this question and more with your answer. Thanks @SLaks!